# Operator does not exist

Tags: postgresql, spring-roo

When trying to create an entity in a Spring-roo PostGres project, I get the following error :

```
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~ unknown
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 433
```

What could be the solution ?

Comment: what is the exact command which gives you this error?

Comment: turn on sql logging if you can and check it out

Comment: yes, please post the sql that throws the error.

Comment: -1 for not showing the actual SQL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type unknown usually occurs when you've a string literal and Postgres ends up trying to decide if it's a varchar, text, literal array, etc.

Cast your string as needed, e.g.:

```
'2'::int
```

Or don't quote it in the first place, if applicable.

Comment: Makes sens. I am wondering if it is not a problem with the type enum in my spring roo project...